# determination of human language from text:: system structure

Tags: java, nlp, language-detection

I'm using [these word lists](http://www.winedt.org/Dict/).

Right now I'm only thinking about German, Russian, English, and French.

I guess what I'm going to do is put them all as part of a hashmap, one for each language with the word as the key, and a boolean as the value.

When I get an input text I'll search over all the lists and whichever has the most hits will be returned as the answer.

Maybe I'll try to use multi-threading and search each of the dictionaries simultaneously using a different thread.

Is that a good solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would work as a first approximation.

The problem with fixed word lists for language detection, though, is that real texts (and especially short ones) may not provide enough hits in your list. A more reliable approach would collect parts of other language features (like statistics of letter n-grams that reflect morphology and orthography), not only full words.

Besides, for some text you may get unexpected results anyway. Consider the following phrase:

> Schwarzenegger in Kindergarten Cop.

For any reader it would be clear that the language here is English. But what tells you that? It is the "in" that makes the phrase unmistakably English. So there are approaches based on short functional words that are assigned much higher weight.

So if you are serious about your project, it would be a good idea to research the area a bit. By the way, why not using one of the existing libraries for language detection? Try [this search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=java%20language%20detection) first. There are also memory considerations (word lists/hash maps can become quite big). But as a quick solution that would work.

Comment: that's a good idea, are there lists of such functional words? __________________________________________________________________________ it's a learning excersize and I'm prohibited from using a library. __________________________________________________________ that's a very funny / good  / creative example.

Comment: It helps to learn the language a little, then you can take them manually. But for a first approximation simply take short words with counts from some very large text.

Comment: Technically speaking, you can treat the problem as a purely statistical exercise: the count for a specific word or letter combination in a sufficiently large corpus of text can be seen as probability. Then, you are building a classifier that tries to assign maximum language probability (called likelihood) based on a number of observations.

Comment: the system I described in the OP is also sort of doing that isn't it? generating a probability based on observed words. in a sense.-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------what do you have in mind? for instance, saving many documents from each language? how is that more efficient that just the words? because you also assign a weight (frequency count) to each word?----------------------- I think the nature of the text would pervert the count, such as specialized domains and the like. a pure list of common words seems better to me.

Comment: For short words you would need the counts, especially because they sometimes overlap across languages, and you need to know how reliable the specific word is. For a plain dictionary approach you are correct, it is probably not necessary.

Comment: actually i don't have any idea though. i think it's a good suggestion and I'm going to try to think about how to implement it. do you have any documentation or references describing it?

Comment: I'm afraid most literature is quite technical, nothing comes to mind to suggest for an "entry level". Also, I don't quite understand the focus of the exercise: is it in coding or linguistics? You need to start with a piece of code that takes a number of texts (from files?) and converts them into feature sequences (calls a function on every feature found, such as word). Then you use it in two ways: an a number of texts of known language for training, and then on a number of texts of known language for testing.

Comment: the excercize was exactly this: "We would also like to ask you to implement a method to identify the language a document is written in. Please do not use an existing library to solve the task, but implement an approach on your own. If you re-implement an approach taken from the literature, please provide a reference. The suggested programming language is Java."

Comment: So it is a programming exercise in a course of computer science?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77963/discussion-between-alex-nevidomsky-and-s-matthew-english).

Answer (score 1):

Unlikely.  Storing that much data in a `HashMap` will consume a lot of RAM.  The problem will only increase as you add support for additional languages.  You'll want to keep your word lists on-disk.  There are many ways to go about it.  You could perform binary-searches on a sorted text file, one for each language.  Or you could store the data in a database, index the text column, and let the DB engine do the work.  You could also use the Full-Text Search capabilities available in many DB engines.  And there are likely more (and probably) better ways than these.  However, the point is that loading the word lists into memory is going to lead to memory problems.

Comment: yeah I suspected that. but can you suggest me maybe one concrete method to try? I don't have much experience with this

Comment: If you just want a demo, forget about memory, just use -Xmx1G in your java command line. But if it is supposed to be a practical library, then trickier methods are required, database is a bad solution for that, too. I would suggest starting with letter 3-grams.